# Wordpress & ACF Plugin - Post editor stops working / crashes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Whenever I install the ACF Pro plugin, I go to the Posts -> Add New and when I click on the Paragraph section under the first heading, I get this - 
[image]

If I click it again or if I try to add any other elements to the editor it will crash like this -
[image]

Just to clarify, I am using the editor in Wordpress. Once the ACF Plugin is removed everything goes back to normal.

I also have this error from "Copy Error"

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Oe (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2:85178)
at https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2:84615
at i (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js?ver=4.17.11:6:91)
at An.filter (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js?ver=4.17.11:99:338)
at we (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2:84592)
at je (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2:85052)
at t.value (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=2.0.2:55:185582)
at ce (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:98:136)
at qg (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:97:440)
at hi (https://theecomdoc.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:104:285)
```

Comment: I'm using ACF Pro on many sites without issue. There might be a plugin conflict between ACF and something else. Your issue isn't related to code per-se, so I'm not sure how much help SO would be for you.

Comment: It ended up being a conflict with the Yoast plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using 11.3 by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I'm using ACF Pro. Just disabled it and everything works like a charm.
Not exactly sure why it is causing the issue!